# json_encode in particular way

Tags: php, json

so this my php

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT name from startup_schema";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $emparray =  array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $emparray[] = $row;
        }
    echo json_encode($emparray);
?>
```

which gives me a JSON like this

```
[{"name":"Flipkart"},{"name":"jagdish"},{"name":"mm"},{"name":"mouse"},{"name":"sa"},{"name":"sdasd"},{"name":"test"}]
```

now what I want is to edit my php code so that I fet a json like this

```
{suggestion: [{"name":"Flipkart"},{"name":"jagdish"},{"name":"mm"},{"name":"mouse"},{"name":"sa"},{"name":"sdasd"},{"name":"test"}]}
```

also notice that there is a square bracket at the starting right now but I want a curly bracket.

Comment: if you echo the result, you can just echo what you want to add too, or concatenate it to the string manually, as simple as that, JSON is stored in a string: `echo '{"suggestion": ' . json_encode($emparray) . '}';` (in your code you forgot the `"` that are needed for valid JSON)

Comment: `json_encode(["suggestion => $emparray]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you change

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
```

with

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $emparray['suggestion'][] = $row;
}
```

you will get your output.

Answer (score 3):

add your data in an array to get the desired result as

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT name from startup_schema";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $emparray =  array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    $arr=array('suggestion'=>$emparray);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```